# Consume in app billing

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, billing, consuming

I have some problems with in app billing, I wanted to create an product inside the app that can be bought several times. But google made the in app billing in a way that a product first must be consumed before you can buy it again. I tried consuming it with the following code:

```
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData1);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        ABActivity.this,
                        "Purchase Successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Bundle ownedItems = mservice.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
                // Check response
                int responseCode = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (responseCode != 0) {
                   throw new Exception("Error");
                }
                // Get the list of purchased items
                ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = 
                    ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                for (String purchaseData : purchaseDataList) {
                    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String purchaseToken = o.optString("token", o.optString("purchaseToken"));
                    // Consume purchaseToken, handling any errors
                    mservice.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken);

                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
            e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The first time I try to buy the item it works perfectly but when I try to buy it again the app crashes. When I try to use the app with a virtual device and log the error with logcat it crashes the first time I try to buy the item and it gives an NullPointerException while the first time on my mobile phone it works perfect, so I don't think the NullPointerException is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with consuming an item.

You can not test the in app billing on a virtual device. This is the reason why you get a NullPointerException.